# Putting a uWSGI fast router in front of uWSGI servers running in docker containers

Tags: uwsgi, docker

I have multiple Flask based webapps running in docker containers (their processes need to be isolated from the host OS). To run these apps I use uWSGI servers inside the containers. Incoming requests should hit a uWSGI FastRouter with a subscription server (as described here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/SubscriptionServer.html). When starting a container, the uWSGI should announce itself based on some internal configuration *as a subdomain*.

So the setup looks like this:

```
Request ---> FastRouter ----> container |     myapp1              |
                        |
                        ----> container |     myapp2              |
```

I'm trying to test this on a single host running both the fast router as well as some docker containers.

The FastRouter is started using

```
uwsgi  --fastrouter :1717 --fastrouter-subscription-server localhost:2626 --fastrouter-subscription-slot 1000
```

**Question 1** Do I need to do anything else to get the subscription server running? Is this started together with the fastrouter process?

The containers have two ports mapped from the host to the container: 5000 (the webapp) and 2626 (to subscribe to the fast router).

So they're started like this:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -p 2626:2626 myImage $PATH_TO_START/start.sh
```

Where in start.sh the uWSGI is started as

```
uwsgi --http :5000 -M --subscribe-to 127.0.0.1:2626:/test --module server --callable env --enable-threads
```

The output looks good, it prints at the end:

```
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 58)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 73, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 74)
subscribing to 127.0.0.1:2626:/test
```

On the host I can do

curl localhost:5001

And I see the Webserver greeting me from inside the container. However, doing

curl localhost:1717/test

gets no response.

**Question 2**

Am I getting anything fundamentally wrong here? Should I test differently?

**Question 3**

How can I debug the FastRouter?

**Edit:**

Still struggling with this setup. I'm using a separate VPS now for the fastrouter. It is started using

```
uwsgi --uid fastrouter --master --fastrouter :80 --fastrouter-subscription-server :2626 --daemonize uwsgi.log --pidfile ./uwsgi.pid --chmod-socket --chown-socket fastrouter
```

**WARNING**: Think before copying above call for your project since it opens up the subscription service publicly - my plan is to secure it afterwards using the key signing facilities provided by uwsgi since the VPS doesn't have a private network available.

`netstat -anp` shows

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      843/uwsgi       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2626            0.0.0.0:*                           843/uwsgi       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9089     843/uwsgi           
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9090     843/uwsgi           
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONNECTED     8764     843/uwsgi           
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONNECTED     8763     843/uwsgi
```

Anyway, using uwsgi nodes with `--http :5000 --module server --callable env --enable-threads --subscribe-to [Subscription-Server-IP-Address]2626:/test --socket-timeout 120 --listen 128 --buffer-size 32768 --honour-stdin` still leads to the same result - uwsgi logs 'subscribing to', but `http://[Subscription-Server-IP-Address]/test` is not reachable. Is this kind of routing even possible? Every example I can find only assigns subdomains like [mysub].example.com, root domains, or root domains with some port number. This page includes a hint that the subscription server should be part of a routable address: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example.

So I have a **follow-up question**:

Is the FastRouter even meant to let nodes announce new routes that haven't yet been set statically in a DNS zone file? I don't really care whether it's http://[key].example.com or http://example.com/[key], what's important is that these keys can be generated from inside a Docker container at setup time of the uwsgi server.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the "dockered" apps run in a different network namespace, so loopback of a docker app is not the same of the fastrouter.

Use unix sockets for subscriptions, they are a great way for inter-namespace communication.

Your commands are good, the fastrouter is pretty verbose so if you do not see messages in its logs it is not working (and eventually you can strace it)

Comment: Thanks roberto, sorry for the long delay. I've just updated my question.

Comment: I feel that I'm pretty close now. I have a http subscription server running on host 1 and uwsgi workers subscribing to it over a public interface on host 2. The subscription server logs `[uwsgi-subscription for pid 926] new pool: test.example.com (hash key: 33469)
[uwsgi-subscription for pid 926] test.example.com => new node: 127.0.0.1:52935`
What's strange is that it assignes nodes from the localhost, since the subscription comes from outside. Then, when a client opens test.example.com, the connection to 127.0.0.1:52935 fails and the route is marked as failed. What am I missing?